# Another formula for Bell numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, generating-functions, oeis

Here is an observation (thanks to OEIS):

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{i^k}{i!}= B_k e,$$ where $B_k$ is the $k$-th Bell number. I might be having reading comprehension issues, but I don't see this formula in the OEIS notes. I assume this is very well known - can someone point me at a reference or a simple proof?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is essentially [Dobinski's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobinski%27s_formula).

Comment: Cool! I am surprised OEIS does not mention it...

Comment: This mentioned a couple of times at least in the notes on A00110, by Jonathan Love in 2007 and by Wolfdieter Lang in 2015. It is in the formulas section by Benoit Cloitre in 2002.

Comment: It's more than "essentially"---it is almost precisely the linked formula :-)

Comment: And a generlized Dobinski formula is used in the proof of a formula for the o.g.f. of the Bell numbers cited in the related questions!

Comment: I didn't know it was Dobinski's formula, but this identity is Exercise 1.9(a) in the first edition of Lovász's *Combinatorial Problems and Exercises*.